Flutter SQLite database limit size length to load external database from assets
I insert SQLite database file in my project and its size almost 2GB. I always got this error message in debug console when running on Android native device:

E/flutter (25145): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(117)] Dart Error: NewExternalTypedData expects argument 'length' to be in the range [0..1073741823].

After googling a long time and read this post I understood, I can't load database file like this size with my method:
Future<Database?> get database async {
  if (_db != null) return _db;

  Directory applicationDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String dbPath = join(applicationDirectory.path, "library.db");
  bool isDBExists = await File(dbPath).exists();

  if (!isDBExists) {
    ByteData database = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "database/library.db"));
    List<int> bytes = database.buffer.asUint8List(database.offsetInBytes, database.lengthInBytes);
    await File(dbPath).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
  }

  _db = await openDatabase(dbPath);

  return _db;
}

I knew after searching and googling these lines aren't working to load large database:
ByteData database = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "database/library.db"));
List<int> bytes = database.buffer.asUint8List(database.offsetInBytes, database.lengthInBytes);
await File(dbPath).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);

And I tried change List<int> to List<Int64> and Uint8List still can't load database and same error!
pubspec.yaml:
dependencies:
  path: ^1.9.0
  path_provider: ^2.1.3
  sqflite: ^2.3.3+1

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/database/library.db

How can I fix this error and load my large database normally?

you want ByteData database to store 2 GB of data in the RAM memory? what is the physical device you want to run that code?

Yes, I want to run this code just in Android devices because I specified my project just for Android OS and I ran this code on my device (Samsung Galaxy A22). @pskink

even thou galaxy a22 has 6GB of RAM memory, it imposes per-app memory limits to ensure system stability and performance, so i am pretty sure you will never be able to load 2GB data in one shoot, most likely you need to divide it into assets/database/library_chunk000.db, assets/database/library_chunk001.db, ... where each chunk has ~10 MB or so - in such case you would need to load ~200 chunks

How can I use chunks? I never used it before! Could solve it please and explain how it works? @pskink

in a loop, read all the chunks in a loop and append each chunk to the output file

Can I share my code with chunks? @pskink
